# Problem in getting SSL Certificate for my domain at digitalocean droplet through Let's Encrypt

Tags: ssl

I was trying to get SSL certificate for my domain on PhpMyAdmin Droplet by following the steps mentioned at "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04". My server is Ok. I have DNS A entry for my domain.com and CNAME entry for my www.domain.com

As I went to execute "sudo certbot --apache -d your_domain -d www.your_domain" 
It asked me to enter email address and after that it gave me the following error.

"An unexpected error occurred:
The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Account creation on ACMEv1 is disabled. Please upgrade your ACME client to a version that supports ACMEv2 / RFC 8555. See https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/end-of-life-plan-for-acmev1/88430 for details.
"

I tried with root and non root admin user with sudo but still the same. Any help is appreciated 
Best

Comment: As the error message says, you need to use a more recent certbot version so that it speaks "ACMEv2" to the server instead of "ACMEv1". So depending on how you installed it, you need to upgrade it. But your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. Did you look at the URL included in the error message? Account creation is disabled since November 2019 on the old interface.

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick, I will explore it further, your reply sounds very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I got it resolved. So first run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --only-upgrade certbot
```

and then

```
sudo certbot --apache -d your_domain -d www.your_domain
```

worked for me

Comment: Good answer, but some explanation would be nice: if you installed certbot with the `certonly` argument, then it gets the cert, but DOES NOT INSTALL IT (from the help: `certonly: Obtain or renew a certificate, but do not install it`), hence, reinstalling without that argument works.